# Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Tags: php

Trying to restore my old web site. It was working without any problems.
Now I get error message: :  **Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in**

```
class Common{
public function __construct()
{
    $parent = new parent();
    $parent->__construct();
    $this->session = Session::instance();
    $this->home = new Home_Model();
}
```

Can anyone explain me why I get error on this line: **$parent = new parent();**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `class Common` didn't have the parent class.

```php
class A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

// Class B use `extends` keyworad to inherit class A, so A is the parent of B.
class B extends A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $parent = new parent();
        $parent->__construct();
    }
}

// This will output 'AA'
$b = new B();
```

If I remove the `extends`, it will show the error `Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent`.

```php
// ...

// Remove the `extends`
class B {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $parent = new parent();
        $parent->__construct();
    }
}

// Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent
$b = new B();
```

By the way, you can use `parent::__construct()` to call the parent constructor.

```php
class B extends A {
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $parent = new parent();
        // $parent->__construct();
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems like it worked. No idea how to make your post solution.